# Mongodb --repair throws a core dump - how do I recover the raw data?

Tags: mongodb

We have a stand-alone MongoDB instance running the latest release via docker.

We had a severe crash yesterday, when one of analysts dropped a database while a separate process attempted to insert a document into one of the collections of the database. Presumably this led to a race condition, but regardless, MongoDB crashed.

We restarted MongoDB, but it kept crashing. We then ran the --repair command and MongoDB threw a core dump.

I can’t find any actual documentation around the --repair command, is it possible to rebuild the database *without* building the indexes? We just need to recover the data.

My question is how do I recover the raw data from the WiredTiger files:

> collection-138-3885477232820226262.wt

Is this just BSON? Is there a way to extract the raw data so I can just re-insert it into a fresh mongodb instance?

thanks!

Comment: You should try this guide https://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2016/02/10/recovering-a-wiredtiger-collection-from-a-corrupt-mongodb-installation/

Comment: thanks for sharing, going through this now. btw, this process should *not* be so complicated, I wonder why @MongoDB doesn't just fix this!!!

Comment: "it kept crashing" leaves too much room for imagination. The crash log would give better idea what's going on there. "the latest release" also not that helpful if people read the answers a year later. You see the blog you was recommended to read has explicit disclaimer that --repair option added in 4.0.3 is a better alternative.  Starting from 4.4 there is no --noIndexBuildRetry option, so you see, version matters. Database config would and command line options you use would help to understand your setup.

Comment: There is not much information on recovery because mongo relies on data duplication and journaling. Running a standalone node implies data is not that important, and is rarely recommended anywhere but development environment. Nevertheless I believe you are not alone facing the problem and I'd be happy to dig into it, just add some details of the error.

Comment: Hey @AlexBlex thanks for the response! I'm running v5.0.6, I'll add more details to the note if it helps.